# What's the process for closing a bad-faith question?

Tags: support

I've started to think that a certain question might not have been asked in good faith.  How would I raise that flag so that it gets reviewed?

Answer (score 4):

You can flag any question and use the reason of "needs moderator attention". That opens up a text field where you can explain what you think the issue is.

Flagging is anonymous so nobody (except the site moderators) will even know the post has been flagged.

Comment: Ah, Fairy Nuff, thanks.